# Print Runtime.getRuntime().exec() output live

Tags: java, runtime.exec, outputstream

I'm writing a Java program that is used to call a PHP script in set intervals. The PHP script outputs a lot of data, and it is the client's requirement that the Java program displays all the PHP script's output while the script runs.

The method I'm using is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"php", "file.php"});
```

Then using an `InputStreamReader` to grab output, primarily using examples from [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4). The problem I'm having is that the stream reader only outputs the data once the PHP script exits (which makes sense considering how the output is looped through).

How would I go about printing the script's output live while the script is running?

Comment: It can be easier to use a `ProcessBuilder` to construct the `Process`.  It allows easy merging of the `System.out` & `System.err`.  +1 on referring to the Java World article.  Since it solves 60% of questions where people **don't** mention it, I feel compelled to link.  ;)

Comment: Good idea. I was actually thinking to do a `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput()` to a file and trying to tail it

Answer (score 5):

I did this by reading the output from a separate thread:

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
  final InputStream stream = p.getInputStream();
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO
      } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
          try {
            reader.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).start();
```

Comment: While the general aproach is your answer is correct, it's rather shaky regarding text encodings. If Java uses a different default encoding than the external process, most non-ASCII characters will replaced with a character from a different encoding. And if UTF-8 is used, then you're likely to cut a multi-byte encoding sequence into two parts sooner or later. Then an encoding exception will be thrown and the thread will exit.

Comment: @Dan I like the idea behind your answer, but it still only displays the script output once the PHP script **exits**. Whenever the PHP script prints out code, i want it to show instantly. Otherwise the script runs for about 2 minutes and outputs a few hundred lines all at once.

Comment: +1 **This answer the question 100%** taking in consideration what @Dan said. Came here for the same issue as op and a copy/paste worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

For now I decided to go with Andrew Thompson's suggestion:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();

InputStreamReader istream = new  InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(istream);

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   System.out.println(line);
}

process.waitFor();
```

This is still not what I'm looking for though, so for now I'm leaving the question unanswered.